# Maximum-Likelihood Estimator of $p_1,...,p_k$ the probabilities of $Y=y_i$ respectively?

Tags: probability, statistics

$y_1,....,y_k$ are the only possible outcomes of Y, and we can assume all of them appear at least once in the sample.

$L(p_1,...,p_k)=\prod_x p_x=\prod_i^k p_i^{\#y_i}$

Normally now I would derive the function but how would you do that with more than one parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Partial derivative with wrt each of the $p_i$'s will give the corresponding MLE's.

Note : As $\sum p_i=1$, you have to replace (say) $p_k$ with $1-\sum_1^{k-1}p_i$. Now is your doubt cleared?

Comment: I don't see it, the partial derivatives are 0 only if $y_i$ is 0

Comment: @CristianDesivo Not at all!! Check my updated answer

Comment: Yes it makes sense, but I'm trying to understand why one way works and thw other don't. Is it that $p_1,..,p_k$ aren't independent but $p_1,...,p_{k_1}$ are?

Comment: @CristianDesivo You can understand somewhat like that for remembering. And please vote and accept my answer if you liked the solution.

Comment: But what is it then?

Comment: @CristianDesivo Actually , as $Y$ is a random variable,so the number $y_i$'s take are random; so  basically in finding MLE of parameters, we first **asume** that $p_i$'s are random variables taking values between $[0,1]$ (although they are actually not, we are just trying to estimate them by doing the experiment) with the constrain that their sum is 1. we then maximise the likelihood function to **estimate** their **best possible values**.